# new QueryOption() throw NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, directory

I've found tutorial about how to filter files in a folder:

```
var options = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileTypeFilter);
var query = Folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

I also have all the using needed so that the code deploys and runs on my phone, but when I arrived at the `QueryOption` constructor, it throws a `NotImplementedException` (empty or with params) with the message: *"The method or operation is not implemented."*

Did anyone of you had the same issue and can tell me how to solve it?

Comment: have you checked the documentation.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207995
 also what if you explicitly declare a new Instance 
`QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.DefaultQuery, fileTypeFilter);`

Comment: I've tryed the explicit declaration and nothing change.

But, when I'm watch at this doc, it seems that it's only supported by Windows OS, not Windows Phone...

Does that means that I can't filter on the Phone part of a universal app? (my code is in the shared project of my app)

Comment: sound like a name space issue.. do all the .cs files in your project share the same name space..? it's really hard to tell without seeing the Class definition of all the relevant code files

Comment: I think I've found what happended... I tryed to launch the same app in windows (not windows phone) and that runs perfectly... So that means that I can't filter on WP :-(

Comment: You'll notice the documentation for this class indicates it's available on Windows only from the icon right under the page title. You are correct that this is not available on Windows Phone.